# Conditional Formatting using Excel writer

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel, using Interop dll I have following code.

```
            objWorkSheet.Range[objExcel.Cells[intHeaderRowCnt + 2, 6], objExcel.Cells[intCellRowCnt, 6]].Formula = "=RC[-3]-RC[-1]";
            objWorkSheet.Range[objExcel.Cells[intHeaderRowCnt + 2, 6], objExcel.Cells[intCellRowCnt - 1, 6]].FormatConditions.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue, Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlGreater, 0, 0);
            objWorkSheet.Range[objExcel.Cells[intHeaderRowCnt + 2, 6], objExcel.Cells[intCellRowCnt - 1, 6]].FormatConditions[1].Interior.ColorIndex = 3;
            objWorkSheet.Range[objExcel.Cells[intHeaderRowCnt + 2, 6], objExcel.Cells[intCellRowCnt - 1, 6]].FormatConditions.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue, Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlLess, 0, 0);
            objWorkSheet.Range[objExcel.Cells[intHeaderRowCnt + 2, 6], objExcel.Cells[intCellRowCnt - 1, 6]].FormatConditions[2].Interior.ColorIndex = 4;
```

How to achieve Conditional Formatting in Excel using Office Writer?

Comment: Code given is using Interop dll

Comment: Please don't add comments to your post, this isn't a forum, it's a Q and A site. This means, it's expected that you [edit your post](http://superuser.com/posts/933007/edit) and include this extra information. By doing this, it means other visitors can see the issue in your post (The question) without having to read a trail of nonsense to get the full story.